# Error retreiving data from phpmyadmin server using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an application where i fetched data from phpmyadmin server hosted on 000webhost , basically it keeps throwing an error and i could not understand what the error is about , because the export json shows that it returns a list of data and i have used json plugin to generate the model class and i feel like everything is alright but i don't know if someone could help , i would deeply appreciate it , Thank you

- This is the error line

```
  End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

- AuthService class

```
 @GET("index.php")
 fun getInfo() : Flowable<DataModel>
```

- MainActivity Code

```
   private fun getInfo(){
        AuthService.getAuthInstance().getInfo()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .toObservable()
            .subscribe(object  : Observer<DataModel>{
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

                }

                override fun onNext(t: DataModel) {
                    Log.d("TAG","Value is ${t[0].data[0].name}")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("TAG","Error is " + e.localizedMessage)
                }

                override fun onComplete() {

                }

            })
```

- I have exported the json file from phpmyadmin and this is how it looks like

```
[
  {
     "type":"header",
     "version":"4.9.5",
     "comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"
  },
  {
     "type":"database",
     "name":"idxxxxxx_info"
  },
  {
     "type":"table",
     "name":"info",
     "database":"idxxxxxx_info",
     "data":[
        {
           "id":"53",
           "name":"xxxx",
           "userName":"xxxx",
           "address":"xxxx",
           "age":"100"
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

Comment: There's a minor point of clarification here; your database certainly is something like MySQL or MariaDB. The phpMyAdmin application exists as a graphical interface for administrators to manage a database instance, but isn't the database itself.

Comment: Further, it's very unclear to me what exactly your problem is. You wrote that you're export from phpMyAdmin is throwing an error, but then posted a JSON file that looks like it came from phpMyAdmin. Since phpMyAdmin is a graphical tool meant to be used manually, you shouldn't be using it as part of your application anyway; it's going to be better to have your own JSON export functionality that ties to MySQL directly.

Comment: Since JSON is not well-defined for data import and export in this case, your parser is going to have to learn the phpMyAdmin syntax and be adaptable to that format (or, again, writing your own JSON exporter). Or maybe connect your application directly to the database rather than passing through JSON as an intermediary data format.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , The database is MariaDB , the problem i have is that i successfully posted data into mydb right , now i want to get back the data from db , i wanted to know how values are stored in db so i decided to export the json file to generate model class , the json i'm showing is the one that i exported from my db which shows the data stored in there .. i set up retrofit to get data from db but it is not working that's the issue .